# Error in reading parts of a binary file C

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles, fread

I am trying to read a binary file in three parts,
one part in the first 20% of the file, the second part is the last 20% of the file, and the last part is the remaining 60%

I have run into a problem, that starts in the reading of the second part and most probably in the third part as well.

Is there a chance I have used `fread()` or `fseek()` incorrectly, since it is the only change? If so, how can I use `fread()` to read only a certain part of the data?

```
int quickScan(FILE* fileToCheck, FILE* virus, int virusLen, int fileLen)
{
    char* buffer = NULL, * virusSig = NULL;
    char result = ' ';
    int firstFile20 = fileLen * 0.2, firstVirus20 = virusLen * 0.2;

    /**
    //first 20% check :
    buffer = (char*)calloc(firstFile20, sizeof(char));
    virusSig = (char*)calloc(firstVirus20, sizeof(char));

    if (buffer == NULL || virusSig == NULL)
    {
        //this means the file is empty, therfor there is no chance it appears in the file
        return 0;
    }

    fread(buffer, 1, firstFile20, fileToCheck);
    fread(virusSig, 1, firstVirus20, virus);

    result = strstrForBinary(buffer, firstFile20, virusSig, firstVirus20);

    if (result != NULL)
    {
        return 1; //found in the first 20%
    }*/
    
    //last 20% check :
    free(buffer);
    free(virusSig);

    int lastFile20 = fileLen - firstFile20, lastVirus20 = virusLen - firstVirus20;

    buffer = (char*)calloc(firstFile20, sizeof(char));
    virusSig = (char*)calloc(firstVirus20, sizeof(char));

    //move the file pointer
    fseek(fileToCheck, lastFile20, SEEK_SET);
    fseek(virus, lastFile20, SEEK_SET);
    
    fread(buffer, 1, lastFile20, fileToCheck);
    fread(virusSig, 1, lastVirus20, virus);
    
    result = strstrForBinary(buffer, lastFile20, virusSig, lastVirus20);
    
    if (result != NULL)
    {
        free(buffer);
        free(virusSig);
        return 2; //found in the last 20%
    }
        //midddle part

    //move the file pointer
    fseek(fileToCheck, fileLen, SEEK_SET);
    fseek(virus, virusLen, SEEK_SET);

    fread(buffer, 1, firstFile20, fileToCheck);
    fread(virusSig, 1, firstVirus20, virus);

    result = strstrForBinary(buffer, (fileLen - firstFile20 - lastFile20), virusSig, (virusLen - firstVirus20 - lastVirus20));

    if (result != NULL)
    {
        free(buffer);
        free(virusSig);
        return 3; //found in the last 60%
    }

    free(buffer);
    free(virusSig);
    return 0; // never been found
}
```

Using the VS debugger I was able to isolate the problem to the function `strstrForBinary()`:

```
char* (strchrForBinary)(const char* string, int charToSearchFor, int len) 
{
    const char ch = charToSearchFor;

    for (; *string != ch; string++, len--)
        if (len == 0) //didn't find ch anywhere in the string
            return (NULL);
    //got here if *string == ch, so return the string from that part foward
    return ((char*)string);
}

char* (strstrForBinary)(const char* haystack, int lenOfFirst, const char* needle, int lenOfInstance) 
{
    const char* subHaystack = haystack;
    const char* subNeedle = needle;

    //change from if (*b == 0) because null isn't the end in binary files
    // if the length of the file ot check is 0, there will never an occourence
    if (lenOfFirst == 0)
        return (NULL);
    //if the length of the file used for checking is 0, it means all of the other file is an instance of the first file
    if (lenOfInstance == 0)
        return ((char*)haystack);

    // match prefix
    for (; (haystack = strchrForBinary(haystack, *needle, subHaystack - haystack + lenOfFirst)) != NULL && subHaystack - haystack + lenOfFirst != 0; ++haystack) {

        // match rest of prefix
        const char* sc1 = NULL, * sc2 = NULL;
        for (sc1 = haystack, sc2 = needle; ;)
        {
            if (++sc2 >= subNeedle + lenOfInstance)
            {
                return ((char*)haystack);
            }
            else if (*++sc1 != *sc2) //HERE IT IS UNABLE TO READ *++sc1
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return (NULL);
}
```

It is unable to read `*++sc1` and crashes there.

I've used this function in other cases and I think the problem isn't in this function, but perhaps in the way I've read the part of the file into `char*` because it worked perfectly fine in every other case. I suspect I'll have a similar problem in the 60% part (although the VS debbuger doesn't specify).

Comment: Why bother with `fseek`? Since you want to read the whole file, just read it all directly into a `char` buffer.

Comment: `int firstFile20 = fileLen * 0.2` is going to round down the buffer size, and even if `int firstFile20 = (int)ceil(fileLen * 0.2)` then the 20% would have to be the absolute limit.

Comment: You have `char result = ' ';` and `if (result != NULL)`. Please check out the compiler warnings for mis-matching types.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It is hard to guess what the problem might be. The inner `for` loop doesn't check that you haven't run out of `haystack` but this may or may not be your immediate problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int lastFile20 = fileLen - firstFile20, lastVirus20 = virusLen - firstVirus20;
```

Last time I checked, if you subtract 20% from a whole, you get 80%. So `lastFile20` is 80% of your file length, and likewise `lastVirus20`.

```
fseek(fileToCheck, lastFile20, SEEK_SET);
fseek(virus, lastFile20, SEEK_SET);

fread(buffer, 1, lastFile20, fileToCheck);
fread(virusSig, 1, lastVirus20, virus);
```

So you skip 80% of each file, and then try reading another 80%. This would place you right at the 160% mark, but that's not a problem, because `fread` will just stop reading at the end. You happily ignore that though, because you are not checking the return value of `fread`, which is a cardinal sin in C programming. Your buffer is only 20% of the file size, but that's about what `fread` is going to read, give or take a rounding error. So if you have a buffer overrun, it's only by a little (insert ironic smiley face here).

Now in the middle part things get more interesting.

```
fseek(fileToCheck, fileLen, SEEK_SET);
fseek(virus, virusLen, SEEK_SET);

fread(buffer, 1, firstFile20, fileToCheck);
fread(virusSig, 1, firstVirus20, virus);

result = strstrForBinary(buffer, (fileLen - firstFile20 - lastFile20), virusSig, (virusLen - firstVirus20 - lastVirus20));
```

You put the file pointer right at the end of the file and then try to read something. That's not a big problem, `fread` will just fail and you will miss your virus match (another ironic smiley). The problem is that your allocated buffers are 20% of the file, but you give `strstrForBinary` 80%. That's a buffer overrun, and by quite a bit this time.

I recommend writing a couple of functions (not tested):

```
const char* readFileFragment (FILE* file, 
                              size_t offset, 
                              size_t size)
{
   char* buf = malloc(needleSize); 
   if (buf == NULL) 
      { /* print an error and exit the program */ 
   if (fseek(file, offset, SEEK_SET) < 0)
      { /* print an error and exit */ }
   if (fread(buf, 1, size, file) != size)
      { /* print an error and exit */ }
   return buf;       
}

int findInFileFragments (FILE* haystackFile, 
                         size_t haystackOffset, 
                         size_t haystackSize, 
                         FILE* needleFile,
                         size_t needleOffset,
                         size_t needleSize)
{

    /* Trivial checks */
    if (needleSize > haystackSize) return 0;
    if (needleSize == 0) return 1;

    char* haystack = readFileFragment(haystackFile, haystackOffset, haystackSize);
    char* needle = readFileFragment(needleFile, needleOffset, needleSize);          
   
    int match = strstrForBinary(haystack, haystackSize, needle, needleSize) != NULL;

    free(haystack);
    free(needle);

    return match;
    
}
```

There is is too much code in `strstrForBinary` and it's all too easy to get confused. There may or may not be another buffer overrun there in the inner loop, it's hard to tell. Here's how I would implement the function:

```
  const char* strstrForBinary (const char* haystack, 
                               size_t haystackLen, 
                               const char* needle, 
                               size_t needleLen)
  {
      while (haystackLen >= needleLen)
      {
          if (memcmp(haystack, needle, needleLen) == 0) 
              return haystack;
          haystack++; haystackLen--;
      }      
      return NULL;
  }
```

(of course something like KMP algorithm is preferred, but one little step at a time).